# Unique code for several CommandButtons in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the captions of several CommandButtons in an UserForm. I know how to get the caption for one CommandButton but I dont want to copy paste the code for all Commandbuttons like

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
CodeXYZ
End Sub

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
CodeXYZ
End Sub

....
```

Is it possible to make something like

```
Sub Master_CommandButton_Click()
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Master_CommandButton.Caption 

End Sub
```

Edit:
I am dynamically loading the captions from a table (depending on row and column). If one of the command button get clicked the caption from the clicked button gets written to a cell.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
CommandButton1.Caption = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value
CommandButton2.Caption = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value
CommandButton3.Caption = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value
CommandButton4.Caption = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value
CommandButton5.Caption = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 5).Value = CommandButton1.Caption
End Sub
```

What I know need is not to define every button itself. I want to hand over a a mastercode to all buttons.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not so clear what you want accomplishing... Do you want having a macro to be allocated/assigned to each button `Click` event and this macro to recognize the clicked one? If so, what `Master_CommandButton`  should be? Is it an example of a button you do not show us in the question ? If not, please better describe what you want accomplisiing.

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi ty for response. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class module to handle the click event of all the command buttons on the form.

Here's one way to do that.

Create a class module named `CCmdBtns` and add this code to it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdGroup As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CmdGroup_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 5).Value = CmdGroup.Caption
End Sub
```

In a standard module add this code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public CmdButtons() As New CCmdBtns
```

Now in the userform module you can add this code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim cnt As Long
    
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CommandButton" Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ctl.Tag = ctl.BackColor
            ReDim Preserve CmdButtons(1 To cnt)
            Set CmdButtons(cnt).CmdGroup = ctl
        End If
    Next ctl
    
End Sub
```

Now when you click any of the command buttons on the userform it's caption will be written to E5 on the active sheet.

Note you could simplify the code for setting the captions by using a loop.

```vb
Dim idx As Long

    For idx = 1 To 5
        Me.Controls("CommandButton" & idx).Caption = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, idx + 1).Value        
    Next idx
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But I have problems to understand it. Why are you writing ````Public CmdButtons() As New CCmdBtns```` to a module. Do you know good literature for classes? I want to learn it :D

Comment: I'll try and find a good link and post it.